# Writing a string array to text file separated by new line character

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP page which accepts input from user in a text area. Multiple strings are accepted as input from user & would contain '\n' and I am scanning it as:

```
$data = explode("\n", $_GET['TxtareaInput']);
```

Each string should be moved into the text file with new line character separation. This is the code I am using now and it separates each string with a '^M' character:

```
foreach($data as $value){
    fwrite($ourFileHandle, $value);
}
```

Is there anyway I can get each string followed by a carriage return?

Comment: `^M` [**is** a carriage return](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraph-table).

Comment: How do I scan for it using sed?

Comment: `\r` should be the proper escape sequence.

Comment: @nickb how do you get code style highlighting in the comments?

Comment: @ryanbwork wrap code in backquotes `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = explode("\n", $_GET['TxtareaInput']);
foreach($data as $value){
    fwrite($ourFileHandle, $value.PHP_EOL);
}
```

Comment: No you will not see `^M` in the file. Do you need to see it?

Comment: ^M still appears in the file. Any ideas why it can be seen?

Comment: Can you give a bit of info about the env/ide involved? what OS are you running this/generating the file in? and what editor are you using to view the file which shows up ^M?

Comment: I am using red hat linux and vim editor. I am not using any IDE for PHP and HTML.

Comment: vi editor shows special character such as `carriage returns(^M)` and `link breaks($)` in the editor. In order to hide the editor showing this information, type in the following vim command in the editor and press enter

`:set nolist`. This will suppress showing those special characters. To see them again just do a `:set list`

This can be seen in vim because, being the powerful editor that it is, it provides such functionalities. This will not affect the content in your file in anyway..

Comment: In the new file I don't want ^M character. How can I replace it? Thank you so much for your help..

Comment: Use this command `:%s/^V^M//g`..note that in the editor you should type it as `CONTROL V CONTROL M` and it will show up as `:%s/^M//g`

But remember that when there is a carriage return in the file, it is a hidden 'meta-character' giving instructions about that data (in this case, specifying that there are carriage returns at such and such places in the file). So when you hard-delete them, it can affect the layout of the data in the file.. Anyways, if what you want to do is remove the ^M from the file, then use the command I pasted above

Comment: This is automated generation of a script. So text from the text area goes into a part of the file. So, additional ^M characters are causing problems. How can those be removed while using fwrite?

Comment: do a `cat <filename>` from shell and check if the ^M char is still showing up?

Comment: No..It doesn't but the formatting is out..I'll have to look into the script again..Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 62):

You can simply write it back using implode:

```
file_put_contents('file.csv', implode(PHP_EOL, $data));
```

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new lines, then why are you first removing them?

```
$data = explode("\n", $_GET['TxtareaInput']);
```

Keep only this line:

```
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $data);
```

It will write your data to the file as it was received.

If you want to replace all new lines by carriage returns before writing to file, use this code:

```
    fwrite($ourFileHandle, str_replace("\n", "\r", $data));
```

Comment: This will not port between windows `(\r\n)` and *nix `(\n)`

Comment: @Raidenace: The OP asked "Is there anyway I can get each string followed by a carriage return?". My code does exactly that.

Comment: Does this work ? `fwrite($ourFileHandle, $data);` Does fwrite's second argument can be array? I think it must be a string and explode gives an array.